# Loading XAML and displaying it properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

I am able to save the Xaml data and then load it again however it doesnt display as I would like it too, this is what it looks like before loading saved data [Before loading saved data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovJtA.png) However after loading all of the buttons disappear [After loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQdWS.png) I would like to keep the buttons where they are and only load the saved data into its allocated space. Below is the code any help would be great thanks.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

// button and code to save canvas
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string savedCanvas = XamlWriter.Save(cnv);
    File.WriteAllText("canvas.xaml", savedCanvas);
}

// button and code for loading canvas
void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    var savedCanvas = File.ReadAllText("canvas.xaml");
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedCanvas);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    Canvas readerLoadCanvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
    Content = readerLoadCanvas;
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Block b = new Block();
    hor.Children.Add(b);
}
```

Comment: What is `cnv`? Consider to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Cnv is the name given to the canvas object in the scene, i will post a MCVE when i am at home as i am currently outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO!  From the code that you've provided, the culprit is this line:

```
    Content = readerLoadCanvas;
```

What you are doing here is replacing your MainWindow's entire "Content" with the canvas.xaml code, therefore it will replace all of your buttons along with the original canvas.  Because I can't see your xaml code (not posted yet), I can't tell what container your Canvas resides in (i.e. Grid, StackPanel, etc.).

But if I were to assume that you put your Canvas inside of a Grid, for example, then I can give you an answer.  Example:

```
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="PanelOfButtons">
            <Button Content="Load" .../>
            <Button Content="Save" .../>
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="cnv" Grid.Column="1" Background="Green">
```

The answer would be to replace the offending line with this to replace the canvas with your new canvas:

```
    // Remove the original canvas
    mainGrid.Children.Remove(cnv);
    // Add the new canvas
    mainGrid.Children.Add(readerLoadCanvas);
```

Comment: Yes the canvas component is contained within a grid and it now works. Thanks.